# Script for Comparing Mocha Test Results

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I want to compare how well several versions of code work 
Our tests are written in Mocha, I'd like a simple script to compare the results of various builds and to provide an output like below.

I feel like something like this should already exist but haven't been able to find it.

Essentially:

```
                    Commit A   Commit B   Commit C
Total Tests Pass        5         4         1
Total Failures          0         1         4

Test #1                 Pass     Fail       Fail
Test #2                 Pass     Pass       Fail
Test #3                 Pass     Pass       Fail
Test #4                 Pass     Pass       Fail
Test #5                 Pass     Pass       Pass
```

I imagine the way it'd be run is by writing a simple script:

```
git checkout <commitA>
mocha test/* --spec <something easy to diff>
git checkout <commitB>
mocha test/* --spec <something easy to diff>
git checkout <commitC>
mocha test/* --spec <something easy to diff>

<some_script> [outputs of each suite]
```

Comment: Just to make sure - you're not considering Jenkins + a test analyzer plugin, correct? Just a pure JS library that can do this for you?

Comment: @rubicon yes, pure JS library